# Freezing graph in tensorflow when using tf.image.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using `tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph` to freeze a tensorflow graph in the function below:

```
def freeze_and_save_graph(self, session, save_dir, name):
    checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(save_dir, "model")
    checkpoint_state_name = "checkpoint"
    input_graph_name = "input_graph.pbtxt"
    output_graph_name = name

    # saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables(), max_to_keep=max_checkpoints)
    checkpoint_path = self.saver.save(
        session,
        checkpoint_prefix,
        global_step=0,
        latest_filename=checkpoint_state_name)
    tf.train.write_graph(session.graph, save_dir, input_graph_name, as_text=True)
    input_graph_path = os.path.join(save_dir, input_graph_name)
    input_saver_def_path = ""
    input_binary = False
    output_node_names = "model_1/output"
    restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
    filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
    output_graph_path = os.path.join(save_dir, output_graph_name)
    clear_devices = False
    freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver_def_path,
                              input_binary, checkpoint_path, output_node_names,
                              restore_op_name, filename_tensor_name,
                              output_graph_path, clear_devices, "")
```

Recently I switch to using `tensorflow.image.Dataset` to do preprocessing like so:

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_train, onehot_train))
data = data.map(lambda x, y: (preprocessing_fn(x), y), num_parallel_calls=32)
data = data.shuffle(len(images_train))
data = data.batch(batch_size)
data = data.prefetch(5)
iterator = data.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
init_op = iterator.initializer
session.run(init_op)
```

After making the change, freezing the graph is taking forever. The size of `input_graph.pbtxt` has gone from 500kB to 150MB. Having a look, the culprit is two tensors with the same size and shape as my training data and with `tensor_content` defined. That is, the training data has been saved in the file.

How can I save the graph without this data?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Use placeholders instead of constructing the Dataset directly from the data. The changes are:

```
image_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=self.x_image.shape)
onehot_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=self.y_true.shape)
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_tensor, onehot_tensor))
```

and

```
session.run(init_op, feed_dict={images_tensor: image_train, onehot_tensor: onehot_train})
```

Now when it saves the graph, it saves placeholders instead of data.

Comment: You can also export a `SavedModel` and freeze that one. When exporting, you replace the input pipeline with a placeholder so that you don't have the pipeline in your inference graph.

Comment: @GPhilo I did not know about `SavedModel`, thanks. Is the protobuf graph file produced any different? Is it able to be served using the tensorflow java library?

Comment: The SavedModel format is just an intermediate before you freeze. The resulting frozen graph file format is the same

Comment: @GPhilo any chance you could give a little more detail on how to swap the input pipeline for a placeholder? The documentation is very sparse.

Comment: Hey @John, would you mind opening a new question for that? The specific answer depends a lot on your code (i.e., if you happen to be using the `tf.estimator` API or, as the OP here, you work with lower level APIs).

Comment: @GPhilo, I posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319765/swap-a-tensorflow-dataset-input-pipeline-with-a-placeholder-after-training). Thanks!