# Tensorflow: optimize grahp for inference. Provide shape for input placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

This question is related to [Swap a TensorFlow Dataset input pipeline with a placeholder after training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319765/swap-a-tensorflow-dataset-input-pipeline-with-a-placeholder-after-training)

I have a graph that I want to optimize for inference with TensorRT. To get the graph, exluding the input pipeline part I do:

```
python optimize_for_inference.py \
--input=frozen_model.pb \
--output=inference.pb \
--frozen_graph=True \
--input_names=IteratorGetNext
--output_names=name_of_the_output_tensor_you_want_to_use
```

"This will replace the IteratorGetNext node with a float placeholder. You might want to choose another node, in which case just change the name. You can also change the type of the generated placeholder via the --placeholder_type_enum option. In that case, you need to provide an integer value matching the datatype you want from the DataType enum." (answer on this question [Swap a TensorFlow Dataset input pipeline with a placeholder after training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319765/swap-a-tensorflow-dataset-input-pipeline-with-a-placeholder-after-training)
)

However, the float placeholder does not have a shape. When doing giving the graph to TensorRT it fails because this shape is missing. Is it possible to give a shape to this float placeholder?

To be more specific, the error given by TensorRT is

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: No attr named
>   'shape' in NodeDef:    [[Node: input_images =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT]] for 'input_images' (op: 'Placeholder')
>   with input shapes: .

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am getting the same issue now.